# Monochrome Pidgin tray icons

Tags: appearance, pidgin, notification-area

Can anyone point me towards monochrome Pidgin tray icons, and tell me how to install them?

(I know I should be using the Messaging Menu indicator applet or whatever it's called, but at the moment I prefer not to, and use the standard Pidgin tray applet)

Answer (score 1):

I think [this](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/08/omg-5-five-monochrome-app-icons/) post at "OMG! Ubuntu" would help you get what you are looking for. If not, I'd recommend you search [the site](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/) as I have run into numerous posts there about monochrome app icons both for the desktop as well as for the indicator applet (a.k.a "tray")